# Can't add element to ArrayList in for loop

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I am currently having the problem of not able to run the following code in Android app development.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test extends FragmentActivity {

ArrayList<String> random;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        for (int a=0; a<11; a++){
        random.add("a");
    }
            }
    }
```

I know the above code does useless action but that is simplified from my problem in the for loop code in JAVA. And I got this error from the error log, "unhandled event loop exception". Can anyone point out that what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Don't make me mock you :) That's not a question for SO!

Comment: @IvanNikolchov sorry. I am only a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems (I suspect).

First, you're getting a `NullPointerException` because you're not initializing `random` with a value referring to an actual object.

Next, your syntax is bad here:

```
for (int a=0; a<11; a++);
```

Your code is only adding a single element to `random` - it's equivalent to:

```
for (int a=0; a<11; a++)
{
}
random.add("a");
```

I very much doubt that that's what you were intending. My guess is that you wanted this instead:

```
for (int a=0; a<11; a++)
{
    random.add("a");
}
```

Comment: Also, perhaps add an integer with random.add(a) was intended, and not adding a String with random.add("a")

Comment: @JustinMuller: Possibly (or rather, `random.add(String.valueOf(a));`. It's hard to tell, with no description about the intended behaviour...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, and the mistake was made when I edited the code on this website while I was trying to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int a=0; a<11; a++) /*Delete the semicolon here*/
{
    random.add("a");
}
```

And also you need to initializing the ArrayList "random"。