# Wrong initialization of ArrayList in a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, initialization

While coding in Android, I needed an ArrayList of Points which I called wormPt. I initialized it through a loop.

```
ArrayList<Point> wormPt = new ArrayList<Point>();
Point pt = new Point();
.
.
.
private void initializeWorm() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pt.x = 220;
    pt.y = 300;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        wormPt.add(pt);
        Log.d("wormdebug", wormPt.toString());

        pt.x -= 5;
    }
    Log.d("wormdebug", wormPt.toString());
}
```

My last log.d should report points 
(220,300)
(215,300)
(210,300)
(205,300)
(200,300)
(195,300)

Instead, all my points are (190, 300)

Here is my log data

```
11-21 23:48:11.549: D/wormdebug(3273): [Point(220, 300)]
11-21 23:48:11.600: D/wormdebug(3273): [Point(215, 300), Point(215, 300)]
11-21 23:48:11.600: D/wormdebug(3273): [Point(210, 300), Point(210, 300), Point(210, 300)]
11-21 23:48:11.600: D/wormdebug(3273): [Point(205, 300), Point(205, 300), Point(205, 300), Point(205, 300)]
11-21 23:48:11.600: D/wormdebug(3273): [Point(200, 300), Point(200, 300), Point(200, 300), Point(200, 300), Point(200, 300)]
11-21 23:48:11.600: D/wormdebug(3273): [Point(195, 300), Point(195, 300), Point(195, 300), Point(195, 300), Point(195, 300), Point(195, 300)]
11-21 23:48:11.630: D/wormdebug(3273): [Point(190, 300), Point(190, 300), Point(190, 300), Point(190, 300), Point(190, 300), Point(190, 300)]
11-21 23:48:14.669: W/KeyCharacterMap(3273): No keyboard for id 0
11-21 23:48:14.679: W/KeyCharacterMap(3273): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

I tried
[Can't add element to ArrayList in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460455/cant-add-element-to-arraylist-in-for-loop) and others, but they don't seem to be having the same problem. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be incorrectly assuming that `wormPt.add()` is cloning `pt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `ArrayList` contains several references to the *same object*. All you're doing in the loop is adding the same reference and mutating the object.

If you change the loop to create a *new* `Point` on each iteration, it will work:

```
int x = 220;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    wormPt.add(new Point(x, 300));
    x -= 5;
}
```

It's very important to understand the difference between *variables*, *objects* and *references*. `pt` is a variable. Its value is a reference to a `Point` object. Unless you ask for a new object, Java won't create one for you. For example:

```
Point a = new Point(10, 20);
Point b = a; // Copies the *reference*
a.x = 100;
System.out.println(b.x); // 100
```

Note that this isn't associating the a and b *variables* with each other - it's just giving them the same value (the same reference). So you could later change `a` to be a reference to a different `Point`, and that wouldn't change `b`:

```
Point a = new Point(10, 20);
Point b = a; // Copies the *reference*
a.x = 100;
a = new Point(0, 0); // This doesn't affect b, or the object its value refers to
System.out.println(b.x); // 100
```

In this case, it's a bit like giving 10 different people a piece of paper with your home address on. If *one* of those people visits the address and paints the front door green, then another of them visits the address, they'll see a green front door.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I'm use to coding in C where we explicitly have to declare references, so I was thinking of the same thing in this case. Anyways, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You must create `new Point` every time when adding to `ArrayList`. Instead there is only one `Point` with changing coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You are adding the same object to the list...

you should created a new object in each iteration of the loop and then add it to the list.

Try something like:

```
wormPt.add(new Point(x, 300));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Statement

`wormPt.add(pt);`

causing addition of same object into ArrayList.

You need to add different object of `Point` to arraylist.

for that you can use
 `new Point(x, y)`
or
you can create an object like
`Point p = new Point(x,y)`

and then add it to the arraylist.